# Why isn't $y = 2\sqrt{(x-vt)^+}$ a travelling wave?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves

From what I understand and has been studied in our course, any equation of the form $f(x±vt)$ is a travelling wave. However, a question at the back of the text states that $2\sqrt{(x-vt)^+}$ is not a travelling wave. Here $(\cdot)^+$ denotes the [positive part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_and_negative_parts).
While the solution has been given, I did not quite understand it; it stated something related to the function having a finite value.

Comment: Make a drawing of it for a few values of $t$.

Comment: The function you describe is infinite as $x\longrightarrow\infty$. So technically its not a wave, though it is traveling.

Comment: @DimitrisK. Please post answers as answers, not comments

Comment: As far as I think that OP tried to write $2(\sqrt x - vt)$

Comment: It is also kind of wonky for values of x less than vt.

Comment: @Knight Probably not. The units don't work in that equation

Comment: @AaronStevens Due to my low efford, I did not think it was worthy of being an answer.

Comment: @DimitrisK. Answers on this site can be of any length/effort. Typically comments should just be for asking for clarification from the OP, or giving suggestions to make the post better. Your comment indeed answers the question, so it would be fine as an answer :)

Comment: Closely related but not quite a duplicate:  [Waves - determining whether a given formula represents a wave](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/161190/140996)

Comment: Which reference? Which page?

Answer (score 1):

The kinetic energy of a small segment of the one-dimensional wave $f(x-vt)$ is proportional to 
$
\left(\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{t}}\right)^2
$, while the potential energy is proportional to $
\left(\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}\right)^2.
$

If $f(x-vt) = 2\sqrt{x-vt}$, its first derivatives with respect to $x$ and $t$ will result in a common factor $\left(\frac{1}{x-vt}\right)$ which diverges as a function of $x$ at fixed $t$, and as a function of $t$ at fixed $x$. Such a divergence of the energy is  clearly  an unphysical result.

**Additional remark.**

Of course, there are other unphysical features of the proposed wave: its divergence for $x \rightarrow + \infty$, at any finite $t$, and its behavior of a diverging signal traveling toward increasing values of $x$, leaving a completely unperturbed state  behind its ending frontwave. Still, such unphysical features could be considered artifact of a partial and non-globally accurate description of a wave (sometimes, in the case of shock-waves, people consider traveling step-like wave profiles supposted  to provide a good description limited only to the  frontwave region.

However, the above mentioned problem, of diverging  energy in the neighborhood of the point where the *phase* $x-vt$ vanishes, remains the most severe among them.